# Why is my site not being centered on the page on mobile or ipad?

Tags: css, mobile, tablet, centering

My test website is looking good on computer browsers, but on iPhone (and I'm assuming other mobile devices) it is not centering the content or the background. On the iPad, it's not centering the background, but is centering the content.

Here's a portion of my css:

```
body {
    background-image:url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-color:#000;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center top;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#container {
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
    height:145px;
}

#nav {
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#main-home-left {
    width:550px;
    background-image: url('../images/text-bkgd1.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-size: 650px auto;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px 50px 0 50px;
    text-align:center;
    min-height: 400px;
}

#main-home-right {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of your #social div. Actually it is not centered in the desktop either. If you look at the bottom you can see the scroll. Your social div has relative but it doesn't have a width property and it's 1000px now. Simply overflowing to right. So you can give your #social div a `width` value or you can give your #header div `overflow:hidden;` property . I hope i express myself. 
Sorry for my English :)